# Finding covariance and variance, sampling without replacement, order matters

Tags: probability, random-variables

Consider a box containing $n$ balls numbered $1, 2, 3, ..., n$. Choose balls from the box at random, without replacement. Let $\xi_k$ be the number on the $k$th ball selected.

How can I find covariance $\mathrm{cov}(\xi_k, \xi_j)$ and variance $\mathrm{var}(\xi_1 + \xi_2 + ... + \xi_k)$?

I think I need to find expected values $E[\xi_k]$ and $E[\xi_k\xi_j]$, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Perhaps start by calculating $\mathbb{E}[\xi_1]$ and use conditional probability to find a pattern for $\mathbb{E}[\xi_k]$?

Comment: Likewise for $\mathbb{E}[\xi_k\xi_j]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed find a pattern (as Keen-ameteur proposes) in the computation of $\mathbb{E}[\xi_k]$ by first looking at $k = 1$ and continuing by conditioning. I've written out what happens for $k = 1,2,3$ and from that you can try to think of how you can generalize the computations for general $k$:

$k = 1$: 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\xi_1] = \mathbb{E}[\text{ number first ball selected }] = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{n}
+ \dots + n \cdot \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1 + \dots + n}{n} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)}{n} = \frac{n+1}{2}.
\end{align*}
$k = 2$:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\xi_2] &= \sum_{k = 1}^n \mathbb{E}[\xi_2 | \xi_1 = k]\mathbb{P}(\xi_1 = k)
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n \mathbb{E}[\xi_2 | \xi_1 = k].
\end{align*}
Now:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\xi_2 | \xi_1 = k] &= 1 \cdot \frac{1}{n-1} + \dots + (k-1) \cdot \frac{1}{n-1} + (k+1) \cdot \frac{1}{n-1} + \dots + n \cdot \frac{1}{n-1} \\
&= \frac{\frac{1}{2}n(n+1) - k}{n-1} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2(n-1)} - \frac{k}{n-1},
\end{align*}
which results in
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\xi_2] &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n \big(\frac{n(n+1)}{2(n-1)} - \frac{k}{n-1} \big) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2(n-1)} - \frac{1}{n(n-1)} \sum_{k = 1}^n k 
= \frac{n(n+1)}{2(n-1)} - \frac{n(n+1)}{2n(n-1)} = \frac{n(n+1) - (n+1)}{2(n-1)} = \frac{n+1}{2}
\end{align*}
So we see that $\mathbb{E}[\xi_1] = \mathbb{E}[\xi_2]$. It turns out that this in general holds, thus $\mathbb{E}[\xi_i] = \mathbb{E}[\xi_j] = \frac{n+1}{2}$ for all $i,j \in \{1,..,n\}$. I will include the computations for $k = 3$ as well:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\xi_3] &= \sum_{l = 1}^n \sum_{k = 1, k \neq l}^n \mathbb{E}[\xi_3 | \xi_1 = l, \xi_2 = k]\mathbb{P}(\xi_2 = k | \xi_1 = l)\mathbb{P}(\xi_1 = l) 
\\ &= \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{l = 1}^n \sum_{k = 1, k \neq l}^n \mathbb{E}[\xi_3 | \xi_1 = l, \xi_2 = k]
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\xi_3 | \xi_1 = l, \xi_2 = k] = \frac{\frac{1}{2}n(n+1) - k - l}{n-2}
\end{align*}
and thus
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\xi_3] &= \frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{l = 1}^n \sum_{k = 1, k \neq l}^n
\frac{\frac{1}{2}n(n+1) - k - l}{n-2} = \frac{n+1}{2}
\end{align*}
where the last step follows from standard calculus.

Now try to prove this holds for general $k$. I think the same methodology can be used in  computing $\mathbb{E}[\xi_k\xi_l]$ (the other term needed to compute the covariance). Thus: first try to compute this for $k = l = 1$ and then for other values of $k$ and $l$ to find a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

For any fixed $t$, there is $(n-1)!$ possible orderings of balls with $\xi_k = t$ out of $n!$ total (with each of them being of equal probability). Thus $P(\xi_k = t) = \frac{1}{n}$.

Similarly, for any fixed $a \neq b$ there are $(n-2)!$ possible orderings, such that $\xi_{k_1} = a$ and $\xi_{k_2} = b$. Thus $P(\xi_{k_1} = a; \xi_{k_2} = b) = \frac{1 - \delta_{ab}}{n(n-1)}$.

Thus $E[\xi_k] = \frac{n + 1}{2}$ and $E[\xi_{k_1}\xi_{k_2}] = \frac{1}{n(n-1)}(\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} - \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}) = \frac{(n+1)(3n^2-n-2)}{12(n-1)}$.

That means, that if $k_1 \neq k_2$, $Cov(\xi_{k_1}, \xi_{k_2}) =  \frac{(n+1)(3n^2-n-2)}{12(n-1)} - \frac{(n+1)^2}{4} = \frac{(n + 1)^2}{12(n-1)}$.

And $Var(\xi_k) = \frac{n^2 - 1}{12}$.

$$Var(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \xi_k) = nVar(\xi_k) + n(n-1)Cov(\xi_{k_1}, \xi_{k_2}) = n(n-1)(\frac{(n^2 - 1)}{12(n-1)} +\frac{(n + 1)^2}{12(n-1)})=\frac{n^2(n+1)}{6}$$